# Groovy - Cannot find nodes in package

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I just recently upgraded to groovy and cloned a catkinized version of a package from github. Whenever I run a launch file, ros tells me that it cannot find the nodes in the packages.

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [package_name/node_name]: can't locate node [node_name] in package [package_name]

The nodes should be in /devel/lib/package_name/ right? I have checked those directories and the executables are definitely there and correctly named.

My environment variables are the following:

```
ROS_PORT=11311
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks:~/ros_packages/src
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.101:11311
ROS_DISTRO=groovy
ROS_IP=192.168.1.101
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/groovy/etc/ros
```

~/ros_packages is my catkin workspace. I tried also adding ~/ros_packages into ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, but that didn't solve the problem.

Am I missing an environment variable? I checked http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables and didn't think any would solve my problem. But I feel like the issue is either missing an environment variable, or not having one set properly to find the nodes in /devel/lib/package_name (if that directory is where they should be).

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66534/groovy---cannot-find-nodes-in-package/) by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 380 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should source `catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` or add it to your .bashrc file

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0